# how to hide a field in elastiquent

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I have this in mapping properties

```
'extra_info' => [
            'type' => 'object',
 ],
```

and after that

```
return Model::searchByQuery($query, null, null, static::OFFSET, $offset, $sortQuery)->paginate(static::OFFSET);
```

I get this error:
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

ps. I was trying to make ajax request.

The thing is that I don't need this field, but if I set enabled=false, or index=no, or store=false(type=string) the index doesn't even generate AT ALL.

Any help? I'm stuck here (( how to not store this field?

Comment: If you return a variable from controller directly, Laravel will make json for you. Please dump `Model::searchByQuery($query, null, null, static::OFFSET, $offset, $sortQuery)->paginate(static::OFFSET);`. It seems that is a string and laravel is failed to make json from this as it is not an object or array.

Comment: problem is that extra_info is in json inside mysql, when fetched, It casts to array and inserts in elastic index as Object(what I don't want). And then in paginate method casts twice into array, i.e. json_decode() gets an array